nVidia P106-090 simply not working on Ubuntu 22.04
Hi I'm trying to install used nVidia P106-090 mining card to work with Ubuntu 22.04, but no matter what I do, it simply won't work.
I've tried all drivers from v390 up to v550 from the aptitude and also from official nVidia website, I had spent some 4 days now just installing/uninstalling, but none of the drivers is working.
Here are the details:
inxi -G

Graphics:
  Device-1: Intel HD Graphics 630 driver: i915 v: kernel
  Device-2: NVIDIA GP106 [P106-090] driver: nvidia v: 550.90.07
  Display: server: X.org v: 1.21.1.4 driver: X: loaded: modesetting unloaded: fbdev,vesa
    gpu: i915 tty: 187x46 resolution: 1920x1080
  Message: GL data unavailable in console. Try -G --display

lspci

    00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v6/7th Gen Core Processor Host Bridge/DRAM Registers (rev 05)
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 6th-10th Gen Core Processor PCIe Controller (x16) (rev 05)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation HD Graphics 630 (rev 04)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family USB 3.0 xHCI Controller (rev 31)
00:14.2 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family Thermal Subsystem (rev 31)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 (rev 31)
00:17.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Q170/Q150/B150/H170/H110/Z170/CM236 Chipset SATA Controller [AHCI Mode] (rev 31)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #5 (rev f1)
00:1d.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #9 (rev f1)
00:1d.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #10 (rev f1)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation H110 Chipset LPC/eSPI Controller (rev 31)
00:1f.2 Memory controller: Intel Corporation 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family Power Management Controller (rev 31)
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family HD Audio Controller (rev 31)
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family SMBus (rev 31)
00:1f.6 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation Ethernet Connection (2) I219-V (rev 31)
01:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GP106 [P106-090] (rev a1)
03:00.0 Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8192EE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
04:00.0 PCI bridge: ASMedia Technology Inc. Device 1187
05:01.0 PCI bridge: ASMedia Technology Inc. Device 1187
05:02.0 PCI bridge: ASMedia Technology Inc. Device 1187
05:03.0 PCI bridge: ASMedia Technology Inc. Device 1187
05:04.0 PCI bridge: ASMedia Technology Inc. Device 1187
05:05.0 PCI bridge: ASMedia Technology Inc. Device 1187
05:06.0 PCI bridge: ASMedia Technology Inc. Device 1187
05:07.0 PCI bridge: ASMedia Technology Inc. Device 1187

nvidia-smi
No devices were found

uname -a
Linux 6.5.0-41-generic #41~22.04.2-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Mon Jun  3 11:32:55 UTC 2 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

dmesg | grep nvidia

[    1.458451] nvidia: loading out-of-tree module taints kernel.
[    1.458459] nvidia: module license 'NVIDIA' taints kernel.
[    1.458463] nvidia: module verification failed: signature and/or required key missing - tainting kernel
[    1.458464] nvidia: module license taints kernel.
[    1.595617] nvidia-nvlink: Nvlink Core is being initialized, major device number 236
[    2.041612] nvidia-modeset: Loading NVIDIA Kernel Mode Setting Driver for UNIX platforms  550.90.07  Fri May 31 09:30:47 UTC 2024
[    2.044134] [drm] [nvidia-drm] [GPU ID 0x00000100] Loading driver
[    6.077728] [drm:nv_drm_load [nvidia_drm]] *ERROR* [nvidia-drm] [GPU ID 0x00000100] Failed to allocate NvKmsKapiDevice
[    6.077899] [drm:nv_drm_register_drm_device [nvidia_drm]] *ERROR* [nvidia-drm] [GPU ID 0x00000100] Failed to register device
[    7.890476] audit: type=1400 audit(1720170548.002:2): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="nvidia_modprobe" pid=356 comm="apparmor_parser"
[    7.890497] audit: type=1400 audit(1720170548.002:3): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="nvidia_modprobe//kmod" pid=356 comm="apparmor_parser"
[    8.033372] nvidia_uvm: module uses symbols nvUvmInterfaceDisableAccessCntr from proprietary module nvidia, inheriting taint.
[    8.108625] nvidia-uvm: Loaded the UVM driver, major device number 511.
[  222.031825] NVRM: GPU 0000:01:00.0: RmInitAdapter failed! (0x24:0x72:1556)
[  222.031941] NVRM: GPU 0000:01:00.0: rm_init_adapter failed, device minor number 0

No matter the driver, every time I get the same outcome, and these are the output messages that I'm seeing over and over. Went through many forum posts as well, and the parts with apt purge nvidia* , reboot after every uninstall and after every install was also done... so if anyone can help what I'm missing I would be really thankful.
